# How do I get django url parameters from a view mixin?

Tags: django, django-views

Exactly what the title says. I have a mixin that needs to pull in the id of a model field in order to be useful. I assume the easy way to do that would be to pull it from the URL.

```
class StatsMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_stats_list(self, **kwargs):
        # the ??? is the problem.
        return Stats.objects.filter(id=???).select_related('url') 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['stats'] = self.get_stats_list()[0]
        print kwargs
        return super(StatsMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Here's the view implementation for reference.

```
class ResourceDetail(generic.DetailView, StatsMixin):
    model = Submissions
    template_name = 'url_list.html'
    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.select_related('url')
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.args` and `self.kwargs`? I think the url params are available using these.

Comment: I thought about kwargs, bug forgot about self. Thanks. facepalm I'll answer my own question when Stackoverflow lets me. (Or you can answer it and I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access URL parameters in Django by using, `self.args` and `self.kwargs`.